# Connect PHP (GoDaddy) to local Oracle Database

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oci8

I've been trying to find a way for a while but I had no success! (OCI, PDO..)
I need Oracle (Express) or something in my php installation.
Could anyone help me? GoDaddy PHP to Oracle DB.

Thanks!

Comment: Almost 500 reputation on SO, you should know better by now.

Comment: @TomKriek I'm in a terrible hurry. I just need to find a guy who knows, I can pay for his time after. Sorry to bother you this much!

Comment: It's not that website..

Comment: I am hoping to be helped by someone who did this before but if only guys with too much extra time like you reply I'll get nowhere. For someone who did this before the details I gave are enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download INSTANT_CLIENT
2. Set `%ORACLE_HOME%` to your instant client path
3. Set `%TNS_ADMIN%` to your `*.ORA` files

   Add `%ORACLE_HOME%` to your `%PATH%`

   Enable the extension `php_ociX.dll` in your `php.ini` file

   Restart your Apache Server

   Follow this example to connect to ORACLE : http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php

Comment: php and oracle are not on the same machine.. how does this help me?

Comment: Yes of course, you can use UNC PATH to set up step 2 and 3, or you can map a network driver in your Web Server

Comment: This looks good, you will need an oracle client installed on the php box to connect to a database on another server.

Comment: @StephanB how to install it on GoDaddy?

Comment: @TraianTatic If you have a (virtual) rootbox then install it by yourself. If you do not have root access to the server then ask them if they install it. They probably won't : (